# The specified child already has a parent-Error

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

This program shows the error "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."
The program has EditText(edText) which asks for input from user.
Its type is NUMBER.(here r is the value from edText)
Below the EditText there is a Button(bt) which displays the edText value.
Below the button (bt) there is another Button(bt1) which again displays the edText Value.
This button must also displays r rows and 4 columns of EditText views i.e, user must enter r*4 input data in EditText.
I cant clear the error and i dont know how to clear that error.
Please help me.Any help is really appreciated!!

Edit : My present code

```
public class Ybus_Activity extends Activity 
{
  int i;
  TableLayout myTL;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_ybus);
  final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  final LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.android_main_layout);
  TextView getData=new TextView(this);
  getData.setText("Enter the number of LineData : ");
  getData.setId(5);
  getData.setLayoutParams(params);
  main.addView(getData);
  final EditText edText = new EditText(this);
  edText.setId(3);
  edText.setLayoutParams(params);
  edText.setWidth(100);
  edText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
  edText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
  edText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());
  edText.setMaxLines(1);
  main.addView(edText );
  Button bt = new Button(this);
  bt.setText("Click to enter Linedata");
  bt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  main.addView(bt);
  final TextView text = new TextView(this);
  bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
  { 
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        String ed=edText.getText().toString(); 

        try{
          i =Integer.parseInt(ed);
         //setting value here
          text.setText(i+"");
         //or you can do like this
         //text.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
          text.setText("Value at TextView is not a valid integer");
        }
    }
});
main.addView(text);
final TextView text2 = new TextView(this);
Button two = new Button(this);
two.setText("Second");
main.addView(two);
main.addView(text2);
two.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        text2.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        main.addView(createTL(i));
    }
  });
}
 public TableLayout createTL(int r)
 {
    int c=4;
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myTL=new TableLayout(Ybus_Activity.this);
myTL.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    myTL.setStretchAllColumns(true);
TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[r];
    EditText[][] et = new EditText[r][c];
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
       tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
      for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
          {
            et[i][j] = new EditText(this);
            et[i][j].setText("o.oo");
            et[i][j].setLayoutParams(params);
            et[i][j].setWidth(100);
            et[i][j].setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
            et[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
            et[i][j].setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());
            et[i][j].setMaxLines(1);
            tr[i].addView(et[i][j]);
            }
      myTL.addView(tr[i]);
    }
//I already have LinearLayout named "main" under onCreate() method...
//main.addView(myTL);
return myTL;
}
}
```

Edit: My present logcat
My LogCat

```
02-23 10:33:19.413: D/AndroidRuntime(1819): Shutting down VM
02-23 10:33:19.413: W/dalvikvm(1819): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2fa2288)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.widget.TableLayout.mutateColumnsWidth(TableLayout.java:583)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.widget.TableLayout.shrinkAndStretchColumns(TableLayout.java:572)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:470)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:435)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-23 10:33:19.502: E/AndroidRuntime(1819):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 10:33:19.632: D/dalvikvm(1819): GC_CONCURRENT freed 151K, 3% free 11037K/11271K, paused 56ms+67ms, total 188ms
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use fill here.  Fill isn't creating new rows, its just adding a copy of the same object into each index of the array.  This means the first time you call  myTL.addView(tr[i]); you set the parent for ALL of the indexes in your array.  The second time it fails because you already have a parent.  You need to create separate table rows in your loop rather than calling fill.

Comment: If i remove that i am getting NullPointerException error

Comment: Because then you haven't created all the TableRows.  You need to new one each iteration through the i loop.

Comment: Arrays.fill(tr, new TableRow(this));  this is what created the trouble for you, it put the same view in every index, instead of creating an array of unique views.

Comment: @GabeSechan I cant get you..will u please explain??

Comment: You created one new view, and put a reference to it at every index of the array with the fill command, instead of creating a new view for every index.

Comment: @user3126670 : If i remove that i am getting NullPointerException error.How to fix this

Comment: see my reply in the seperate answer

Comment: @user3126670 : If i add "tr[i]=new TableRow(this);" this line i am getting arithmetic exception error..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48179/discussion-between-gkn06-and-user3126670)